# uintptr_t portable alternative

Tags: visual-c++, memory, alignment, pointer-arithmetic

I want to perform check for memory alignment of some type `T`. The straightforward way to do this is

```
if (((uintptr_t)&var & __alignof(T) - 1) == 0) ...
```

however, `uintptr_t` is not part of existing C++ standard and it is not supported by some compilers, so I'm looking for a portable alternative way to do this and `std::ptrdiff_t` looks good for me. `std::ptrdiff_t` guaranteed to be able to store difference between two pointers, but who says that one of those pointers cannot be null pointer? In that case `std::ptrdiff_t` has to be at least same size as the pointer itself.

```
template <typename T> bool is_properly_aligned(const T* const ptr)
{
    std::ptrdiff_t diff = (ptr - static_cast<T*>(0)) * sizeof(T);
    return ((diff & __alignof(T) - 1) == 0);
}
```

or like that (to get rid of multiplication by `sizeof(T)`)

```
template <typename T> bool is_properly_aligned(const T* const ptr)
{
    std::ptrdiff_t diff =
        reinterpret_cast<const char*>(ptr) - static_cast<const char*>(0);
    return ((diff & __alignof(T) - 1) == 0);
}
```

What do you think about such kind of solution? Is it portable enough? I don't see any reasons why this should fail, however I would like to confirm.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the question here is. "What do you think?" I think ptrdiff_t is indeed the correct datatype to represent the difference between two pointers, but it makes very little sense to compare two pointers if they are not pointing into a block of contiguous memory that comes from a simple allocation (and as a corollary, neither of the two pointers being compared should ever be NULL).

Comment: You wrote `I think ptrdiff_t is indeed the correct datatype to represent the difference between two pointers`. My question is what do you think, is it portable to store pointer integer representation in ptrdiff_t?

Comment: You wrote `but it makes very little sense to compare two pointers if they are not pointing into a block of contiguous memory that comes from a simple allocation`. I'm not comparing, I'm calculating the distance and purpose of this is to get integer representation of pointer.

Comment: But ptrdiff_t is not a numeric type like int. It's not even guaranteed to be the same size as int (and on 64-bit systems, it usually isn't). If you want to play games like that, you might as well just cast (int)ptr, and check the lower bits for alignment.

Comment: You wrote: `But ptrdiff_t is not a numeric type like int.`. From standard `The type of the result is an implementation-defined signed integral
type`